# Is it possible to extract function signatures from object files?

Tags: c, function, object, header, reverse-engineering

I have the (C) object files of a program. I can de-assembly them (with objdump) I want to rewrite some function. I approximately know the behavioral of these functions, but I don't know the parameter list of them. Is it possible to get full name with return value and parameters back of a function from the object files?

I know that in c++ the function name contains these information but in c it does not.

Comment: The calling convention depends on the processor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention

Comment: There are C and C++ decompilers -- programs that attempt to convert compiled object code to corresponding C or C++ source code.  It sounds like that's what you want.  Specific recommendations would be off-topic here.

Comment: You should give asking this question on the SE [Reverse Engineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) site a shot. You will probably get more helpful answers there

Answer (score -2):

`nm -C` followed by grepping for the function(s) you need should do the job.